# How to get a column of checkboxes in Gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

One note is that I'm doing this all in Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web.

I have a GridView, and its data is being generated by a SqlDataSource. Currently, when I test the page. A table like below gets generated:

```
CustomerID    CustomerName    CustomerAddress
-----------   ------------    ----------------
1             Bob             Address
2             John            Address
3             Smith           Address
```

However, I really want this:

```
CustomerID    CustomerName    CustomerAddress
-----------   ------------    ----------------
[]             Bob             Address
[]             John            Address
[]             Smith           Address
```

I want the CustomerID field to be "hidden field" and have a checkbox in its place. Then, I want the value of the checkboxes to be the CustomerID for that row. However, I can't for the life of me get the checkboxes in there, and it's still just displaying the CustomerID itself. In the end, I want to create a button that will delete the rows of whatever is checked, and have it reflected in the database via a `DELETE FROM TABLE`. This is why I want the checkboxes to also "have" a value of whatever the CustomerID is for that particular row.

Here's the code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CustomerID" DataSourceID="RowsInGroup" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="CustomerID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CustomerID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerName" HeaderText="CustomerName" SortExpression="CustomerName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerAddress" HeaderText="CustomerAddress" SortExpression="CustomerAddress" />
                <asp:TemplateField></asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

If there's a better Data object to use in the Toolbox, I'm all ears.

Thanks for any advice you can provide!

Comment: Could we see your GridView code, please? It will be easier for us to see what you need to do differently.

Comment: Sorry, can't believe I forgot that.

Comment: No problem. How exactly do you want the checkbox to work for a CustomerID? Generally a checkbox is related to some boolean value.

Comment: When I coded this in Classic ASP, the checkbox had a value. Then, I created a function that would run through the table to see which checkbox was checked. So if I checked the 1st and 3rd box up above in the example, it would return to me: 1, 3.      

I was hoping for something similar, but ASP.NET is quite different. What I'm planning to do is create a button that will "delete" whatever is checked and have it reflected in the database. That's why I need the values to stick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have half of your problem solved. By using `DataKeyNames="CustomerID"`, you have no need for a hidden field to hold this value.

First, create your check box column. There are multiple ways to accomplish this. Here is one:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDelete" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then in whatever event handles the delete, just iterate each row in the GridView and find the checkbox in each row. If it is checked, use the `DataKey` for that row to get the `CustomerID`.

```
protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> customersToDelete = new List<string>();
    foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chkDelete = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkDelete");
        if(chkDelete.Checked)
        {
            DataKey key = GridView1.DataKeys[row.DataItemIndex];
            customersToDelete.Add(key.Value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks for the very informative post!